# Change tab styling for all tabs except the one being clicked

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, styling

So I have a few tabs. There can be multiple tabs, but I currently have 3. What I am trying to do is to change the styling of the tab when it is clicked and the other tabs to have some other styling. My code is as follows:

```
    <div id="ClaimTabs" class="TabbedPanels">

        <div class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
            <div id="list1" class="TabbedPanelsTab TabbedPanelsTabSelected">
            <a id="anchor1" class="TabbedPanelAnchor" href="javascript:showTab(1);">Tab 1 </a>
            </div>

            <div id="list2" class="TabbedPanelsTab">
            <a id="anchor2" href="javascript:showTab(2);" >Tab 2</a>
            </div>

            <div id="list3" class="TabbedPanelsTab">
            <a id="anchor3" href="javascript:showTab(3);">Tab 3</a>
            </div>

        </div>



        <div id="ClaimContent" class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
            <div id="tab1" class="TabbedPanelsContent TabbedPanelsContentVisible" style="display: block;">
            Screen 1
            </div>

            <div id="tab2" class="TabbedPanelsContent" style="display: none;">
            Screen 2
            </div>

            <div id="tab3" class="TabbedPanelsContent" style="display: none;">
            Screen 3
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

My script that manipulates the styling is as follows:

```
function showTab(tabNumber) {
        var children = document.getElementById('TabbedPanelsTabGroup').childNodes;

        document.getElementById('tab'.concat(tabNumber)).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('list'.concat(tabNumber)).setAttribute("class", "TabbedPanelsTab TabbedPanelsTabSelected");
        document.getElementById('anchor'.concat(tabNumber)).setAttribute("class", "TabbedPanelAnchor");

        for(i=1; i <= children.length ; i++)
            {
                if(i != tabNumber){

                    document.getElementById('tab'.concat(i)).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('list'.concat(i)).setAttribute("class", "TabbedPanelsTab");
                    document.getElementById('anchor'.concat(i)).setAttribute("class", "");
                    }
            }
        }
```

I was wondering if my logic is right. I am concatenating the tab, list and anchor with the number and updating styles. But this does not seem to be working.

Comment: It would be easier to do this with jquery and css classes instead of using pure javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have at least two problems here.

First, you're trying to use `document.getElementById` for `TabbedPanelsTabGroup`, but that's a class.

Second, you're using `.childNodes` when you are probably looking for `.children`. `.childNodes` includes all child nodes, including the text inside the tags (which is a node). So when you use that number to loop over it, your loop isn't counting to 3 (your # of divs), it's counting to 7, and that's giving errors.

But, `.children` isn't supported before IE9, so like others have suggested, you may want to consider jQuery to get at that with better support.

Answer (score 0):

With plain JavaScript I would recommend EventListener:

```
<div id="elem"> "some content here" </div>

var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
elem.addEventListener ('click', show, false);

 function show() {
    //add css Class
    var element = document.getElementById("elem");
    element.classList.add("activeTab");
 }
```

But as mentioned in the comment, jQuery is perfect for that kind of things.

best

M

Comment: I am new to all this. Can you tell me where I need to start my search for solving a problem like this with jQuery?

Comment: I like the way it is described here: http://learn.jquery.com/ - you may start at the first chapter and later take a look at the events: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/ - it's just adding a active css class (.addClass) to the container you clicked on and if you click on the second or third tab remove it again (.removeClass) - hope this helps. M